# Is it possible to build a route profile for a street with "real" heights considering tunnels and bridges?

Tags: qgis, routing, elevation, streets

Is it possible to build a exact route profile for a street with "real" heights considering tunnels and bridges in an easy way with free data? Of course it is possible to remove thy waypoint located on ab bridge but for a longer route it's a lot of work. Is there any easy way to build a "street model"?

Comment: With GraphHopper that is definitely possible (with just open data!) but not yet done regarding tunnel/bridge issue: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/713